Playing twilio asset from http parameter
I have an automated call using a twilio twilml bin
<Response>
  <Say>This is reminder day number {{day}}</Say>
  <Pause length="1"></Pause>
  <Play loop="2">{{audio}}</Play>
</Response>

The say command works with the http parameter passed in, but the audio is not playing,
When I put the url to the audio straight in the play tag it works.
https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH078d6c890d5f58a255f47841ceeb4cc3?night=2nd&audio=https://salmon-manatee-9636.twil.io/assets/2nd%20Day.wav
How can I play an audio file from a http parameter?

It might be related to the url-encoding of the audio url. Can you also add the URL of the TwiML that you call (incl the query parameters) to the question?

@IObert I added it to the question

I assume you run into this problem because you didn't URL-encode the audio query parameter. The link above will explain the detailed rules but it basically failed because you had a (audio) URL as the query parameter or another (TwiML Bin) URL.
The right URL would be:
https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH078d6c890d5f58a255f47841ceeb4cc3?day=4&audio=https%3A%2F%2Fsalmon-manatee-9636.twil.io%2Fassets%2F2nd%2520Day.wav

